# ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings Obsolete

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am getting a warning when using this:

> ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings("ArbitraryName").ToString()

**The warning:**

*Public Shared ReadOnly Property AppSettings As System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection' is obsolete: 'This method is obsolete, it has been replaced by System.Configuration!System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings'.*

I have tried using ..

> ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ArbitraryName"].ToString();

```
*The issue with this  is that it cannot be casted as a string.*
```

Note: My System.Configuration is pointing to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Configuration.dll

Comment: What is the exact error when you use ConfigurationManager? (And you don't need the ToString(), it is already a string)

Comment: Wait, are you using the square brackets in VB.NET to index the key of the collection?

Comment: @Steve Thanks. This solved the issue. I used square brackets instead of curly brackets smh.

Answer (score 1):

This should work..

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ArbitraryName")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in aspx file.
Error message: Too many arguments to 'Public Shared Overloads ReadOnly Property AppSettings As NameValueCollection.
Fix:
Change

`<a href='<%ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("URL") %>'></a>`

To

`<a href='<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("URL") %>'></a>`